# Twilio - TwilioClientService stopwithTask equals true why?

Tags: android, service, android-manifest, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I want to get answer from Twilio Evanglists that in BasicPhone Sample App of Twilio Android SDK contains : `<service android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" android:exported="false" android:stopWithTask="true"/>`. I want to know why ?

Comment: Hi Yogesh, Megan from Twilio here. I'm not 100% sure what you are asking. What part of that do you want to know why about?

Comment: @Megan I want my app to listen for incoming call when it is not in view